# Validate XSD: Opening and ending tag mismatch

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm trying to practise the transformation from XML DTDs to XSDs.
This my first try but the w3-validator throws this error for the following XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<!-- Kurskatalog -->

<xs:element name='Kurskatalog' type='Kurskatalog_t'>
<xs:complexType name="Kurskatalog_t">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Kurs" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="Kurs_t"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- Kurs -->

<xs:complexType name='Kurs_t'>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Anbieter" type="DUNS_t"/>
<xs:element name="Nummer" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Bezeichnung" type="xs:integer"/>
<xs:element name="Startdatum" minOccurs="0" type="xs:date"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- simpleType -->

<xs:simpleType name="DUNS_t">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:pattern value="[0-9]{9}"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

The Validator tells me:

> Error on line 31 at column 13:
>   Opening and ending tag mismatch: element line 0 and schema

I'm sure this a pretty simple mistake but I don't get it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the `Kurskatalog` element declaration by changing this

```
<xs:element name='Kurskatalog' type='Kurskatalog_t'>
```

to this

```
<xs:element name='Kurskatalog' type='Kurskatalog_t'/>
```

and your error will go away.